# No data received from wrapped SSLsocked, Python

Tags: python, sockets, ssl, python-3.4

I am writing TLS server in Python. I accept a connection from a client, wrap the socket and then try to read data - without success.

My server inherits from socketserver.TCPServer. My socket is non-blocking - I overwrote server_bind() method. Socket is wrapped, but handshake has to be done separately, because of the exception which is raised otherwise:

```
def get_request(self):
    cli_sock, cli_addr = self.socket.accept()
    ssl_sock = ssl.wrap_socket(cli_sock,
                              server_side=True,
                              certfile='/path/to/server.crt',
                              keyfile='/path/to/server.key',
                              ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1,
                              do_handshake_on_connect=False)
    try:
        ssl_sock.do_handshake()
    except ssl.SSLError as e:
        if e.args[1].find("SSLV3_ALERT_CERTIFICATE_UNKNOWN") == -1:
            raise
    return ssl_sock, cli_addr
```

To handle received data, I created a class which inherits from socketserver.StreamRequestHandler (I tried also with BaseRequestHandler, but with no luck, ended with the same problem - no data received).
When I print self.connection in handle() method, I can see that it is of type SSLSocket, fd is set (to some positive value), both local and remote IP and port have values as expected, so I assume that a client is successfully connected to my server and the connection is opened. However when I try to read data

```
self.connection.read(1)
```

There should be more bytes received, I tried with 1, 10, 1024, but it does not make any difference, the read() method always returns nothing. I tried to check len or print it, but there is nothing to be printed.

I was monitoring packages using Wireshark. And I can see that the data I am expecting to read, comes to my server (I checked that IP and port are the same for self.connection and in Wireshark), which sends ACK and then receives FIN+ACK from the client. So it looks like the data comes and are handled properly on a low level, but somehow read() method is not able to access it.

If I remove wrap_socket() call, then I am able to read data, but that is some data which client is sending for authentication.

I am using Python 3.4 on Mac machine.

How is that possible that I can in Wireshark that packets are coming, but I am not able to read the data in my code?

Comment: When doing a socket recv or read and getting 0 or None, that means the connection terminated. It sounds like the client connects but the handshake never happens properly. Getting the FIN+ACK sounds like the client might be closing the connection early. Why are you doing the handshake separately? In anycase you should post that code here and also attach the packet capture.

Comment: @chemdt I assumed that connection was not terminated, because when I tried to 

    print(self.connection)

I have not seen "[closed]" info.
And FIN+ACK came after data - at least according to packets in Wireshark; I was not able to read any data in my Python script, as I wrote in my first post.

Comment: The issue is now solved. It was indeed a problem with handshake - ignoring the exception was not a clever solution. I had a bug in authentication method on client side. Once I fixed that, I was able to read data on server side - and I could no longer see them in Wireshark (which probably means that they were encrypted).